# JQuery não exibe prewier de imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, multiple-file-upload

boa noite, estou tentando fazer um prewier de imagem em um campo file com múltiplos uploads.

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Upload Ajax</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_global/_funcoes/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/upload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="principal">
     <h1>Envie suas Fotos</h1>
     <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="fotos" id="fotos" multiple>
        <button type="submit" id="botao">Enviar Fotos</button>
     </form>    

     <div id="resposta"></div>

     <ul id="listaFotos"></ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

js

```
// JavaScript Document
(function () {
  var input = document.getElementById("fotos"), 
  formdata = false;

  function exibeItem (fonte) {
      var lista = document.getElementById("listaFotos"), 
          li = document.createElement("li"),
          img = document.createElement("img");

          img.src = fonte;

          li.appendChild(img);
          lista.appendChild(li);
  }

  if(window.FormData) {
      formdata = new FormData ();
      document.getElementById("botao").style.display = "none";
  }

  input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
      document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = "Enviando Fotos..."

      var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

      for (; i < len; i++) {
            file = this.files[i];
            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                if (window.FileReader) {
                    reader = new FileReader ();
                    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                        exibeItem (e.target.result, file.fileName);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
                }

                if(formdata) {
                    formdata.append("fotos[]", file);
                }
            }
      }
      if(formdata) {
          $.ajax ({
              url: "upload.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: formdata,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              success: function(res) {
              document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = res;
              }
              });
      }
      }, false) 
}());
```

php

```
<?php
  foreach ($_FILES["fotos"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
     if ( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
         $name = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][$key];
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][$key], "upload".$name);
     }
  }

  echo "<h1>Fotos enviadas com sucesso</h1>";
?>
```

Acontece que o código esta parando na linha 2 do js dizendo que o elemento de id "botão" não exite e existe.

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Poderá ter a ver com estares a usar uma `self invoking function` [no principio do document]* em vez de estares a usar o `ready` do jQuery; uma self-invoking-function é corrida *assim que* o motor do javascript a vê - ora, nessa altura o DOM ainda não está ready portanto (efectivamente) o elemento `#botão` nao existe.

Tenta usar `$(document).ready(function() { ... } );` em vez de `(function() { ... }())`

*se meteres essa self-invoking **no fim** do HTML (ou seja, ao pé da closing-tag do body) essa funcção irá funcionar que nem ginjas :)